# SSRS with Custom Authentication not able to connect SSAS Cube

Tags: sql-server, authentication, reporting-services, ssas, cube

I am trying to connect Analysis Services Cube from Reporting services thru Custom Authentication. It is not allowing as the documentation says Only Windows authentication is allowed to connect to cube.

> Client Users connect to   -->    Reporting Services (ServerA) (using custom Auth)    -->   Tabular Model AS Cube(using Row Level Security Enabled ) Server A(same as RS)

Versions :

> All SQL engine, SSAS, SSRS in 2016.

Problem Statement: I am able to successfully Connect Reporting Services thru Custom-Forms authentication by implementing CustomSecurity Extension. But after getting in to SSRS thru custom login I am not able to connect SSAS thru custom Security. What are all options available for me to connect SSAS Cube thru Custom Security?

Comment: Looking into this, I found an interesting blog. THis might be of help. https://sqlserverbi.blog/2016/06/13/row-level-security-just-got-better-passing-report-credentials-to-analysis-services-in-sql-server-2016/

Comment: Very nice blog... Probably that is one of my options or only option to look..

Comment: Can you put your comment as answer so that I will UPVote and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into this, I found an interesting blog. THis might be of help. https://sqlserverbi.blog/2016/06/13/row-level-security-just-got-better-passing-report-credentials-to-analysis-services-in-sql-server-2016/

Comment: It works good... But only problem is I require to configure a windows ID...